# React Cleanup async function fetch with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-effects

This is in a functional component.

I have a `submit()` function that looks like so:

```
  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      let resp = await fetch("FOOBAR/BAX", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ /*stuff*/})
      });
      if (resp.ok){
        // yadda yadda yadda
        props.history.push("/"); // navigate
      }
    } 
  }
```

Now, when I cause navigation to occur I'm getting the dreaded 'Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.' error.

So, using effects, how do I make sure this fetch call is cleaned up?  All the examples I'm seeing use `useEffect` to both set up and then cleanup the call (with cleanup function).

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any state change in your `handleSubmit` function. I don't see anything to clean here. Would you care to share more code, maybe on stackblitz?

Comment: @yonki Thanks, maybe my assumption is wrong.

Comment: @yonki let's say I want to make sure that request is cancelled -- how would I useEffect to do that?

Comment: @mtyson I believe @yonki is informing you that the error doesn't match the code you shared. Your `handleSubmit` function doesn't appear to update state (unless it is hidden within the yadda yadda yadda bit). About using `useEffect` hook to cancel a fetch request you can use an [abort controller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) with the fetch request. Let us know if you need help with that. In the mean time , as yonki requested, can you share more of the component code or share a link to it in stackblitz or codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clean up a fetch request by cancelling on dismount using an [abort controller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)**

Factor the fetch request logic out of the handler into the effect hook and use a state hook to trigger the effect to fire. Return the controller's `abort` function in the effect hook to be called when the component unmounts.

```
const [body, setBody] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const signal = controller.signal;

  if (body) {
    fetch("FOOBAR/BAX", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      signal, // add signal to request
    })
    .then(res => {
      setBody(''); // clear request body value
      if (res.ok) props.history.push('/');
    });
  }

  return controller.abort; // return the abort function to be called when component unmounts
}, [body]);

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setBody({ /*stuff*/ }); // set request body value to trigger effect to fetch
};
```

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/amazing-elgamal-74h16?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) with this implemented as a react hook, with manual abort and automatic abort on unmounting.

Comment: @mtyson Thank you, that is very kind of you to say. I just noticed and fixed a typo I had in the effect hook though, the dependency should be on `body`, not `request` that I had initially called that variable. Hopefully that didn't trip you up.